# Minimize time to complete N tasks on P agents

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks

I have N tasks where the i'th task takes `A[i]` time to process. Every task is independent of each other and can be scheduled anytime on any of the P processors. A task can be run on only 1 processor, and a processor can process any number of tasks. Each agent/processor can only work on one task at a time, and once begun, must continue to work on it until the task is complete

I want to minimize the amount of time it takes to complete all the task

I am implementing this using a min-heap, i.e.

1. Sort the task in descending order
2. Create a min-heap of size P initialized to 0
3. For each task i, pull the min from heap, add the task time `A[i]` to it and add it back to the heap

The time to complete all the task is maximum value in the heap. This has been working so far and I want to verify its correctness

Do you think this breaks for any inputs?
I believe I am doing something like [Greedy Number Partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_number_partitioning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a polynomial time algorithm for a problem that includes NP complete problems as special cases (for example with P=2, you have a subset sum problem). Therefore you should expect it to not always work.

The simplest case I could find where your algorithm breaks is if the weights are `1, 1, 5, 5` and `P=2`.  Your algorithm should combine things like this:

```
1 1 5 5
1,1 5 5
1,1,5 5
```

and will take 7.  The better solution you don't find is:

```
1,5 1,5
```

which will complete in 6.

Comment: I don't follow, with my algorithm it does find 6 as the answer. You need to sort the task times in descending order

Comment: @ffff Then I do not understand the description of your algorithm.  Code would have clarified.  What does it give for 2 processors and task times `2, 2, 2, 3, 3`?  Does it find `[2,2,2], [3,3]` for 6? But regardless of whether that example works, the fact that you have a simple polynomial solution to a well-studied NP complete problem says that SOMETHING is wrong.

Comment: it does fail for that input. i get 7. the code is here https://gist.github.com/fhalde/257252d2a076e0e6a2ff1562583289a0

Comment: it looks like i implemented https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest-processing-time-first_scheduling whose results aren't always optimal